# How to execute a variable-sized array of promises in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, winjs-promise

I'm working on a piece of code to request information from an API. Throttles at 10 requests per second.
My solution was to Promise.all(calculate(item1),calculate(item2)... ) and so forth for the 10 requests.

My approach was questionable to say the least, because when I have less than 10 items to check, my Promise.all is half done, and errors.

How can I populate Promise.All() to adapt to the length of the array?

I know this may sound idiotic and although my solution works, it's awful. I'm just a begginer and although I can handle some stuff, callbacks inside a Promise.all is way out of my league lol.

Thanks in advance!

```js
async function superCalculadora(it){
    let res;
    if (it.length < 5) {
        if (it.length == 4) {
            res = await Promise.all([calculadora(it[0]),calculadora(it[1]),calculadora(it[2]),calculadora(it[3])]);
        }
        else
        {
            if (it.lenght == 3){
                res = await Promise.all([calculadora(it[0]),calculadora(it[1]),calculadora(it[2])]);
            }
            else
            if (it.length == 2){
                res = await Promise.all([calculadora(it[0]),calculadora(it[1])]);
            }
            else
            if (it.length == 1){
                res = await calculadora(it[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        res = await Promise.all([calculadora(it[0]),calculadora(it[1]),calculadora(it[2]),calculadora(it[3]),calculadora(it[4])]);
    }
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and replace all of the above code with:

```
async function superCalculadora(it){
    const res = await Promise.all(it.map(item => calculadora(item)))
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I never learned how to properly use some of those functions. That helps a lot!! You're awesome. You just cleaned up my code and saved me around 50% processing time.

Comment: Awesome! I use most of the array functions regularly, definitely worth learning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array.